# Hosted Blazor WebAssembly with SignalR Chathub won't connect

Tags: asp.net, signalr, blazor-webassembly

I'm following some Blazor Tutorials at this URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly.

It has two versions:

- Blazor Server
- Blazor WebAssembly

I have a problem on the WebAssembly version.
When I run the Hosted WebAssembly version with SignalR Chat it works in debug mode.  But when I run without debugging it does not work.  The Send button is disconnected.
And I get an error in the console:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()"
Then it says method 405 is not allowed.

If I point the browser to the chathub URL:
localhost:portnum/chathub,
the browser says, "Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

**Working in debug mode**
[image]

I was going to upload a picture here with the error running in non-debug mode but it magically started working.

I'm not sure if this is an issue now.  I'll keep this question updated and delete if I can not replicate later.

I know I've had an issue in ASP.Net Core/Angular projects in development sometimes the client side would error out because it finished compiling and loading before the server side endpoints host.  So it might be something like that.